# AngularJS not working when paired with RequireJS. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am trying to build a very simply demo to get AngularJS working with RequireJS.

Up to this point I have been closely following [this tutorial.](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/04/integrating-angularjs-with-requirejs/)

I have defined a main.js file, which requires both app.js and hello.js, which are both called in turn.

app.js defines a new Angular module and returns it. hello.js then adds a controller named 'Hello' to the module.

In the page itself, the div should output 'Hello', which is returned by the sayHello method in the Hello controller. However, all my browser shows is {{sayHello}}.

Comment: You probably would wanna have a look at the angularjs-requirejs-seed project, which does exactly what you're trying to do: https://github.com/maxdow/angularjs-requirejs-seed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like [Shay Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104775/shay-friedman)'s solution worked.

I had seen [Angularjs + RequireJs + Express Seed](https://github.com/maxdow/angularjs-requirejs-seed) mentioned before, but I was sure there was a way to do the same thing by itself without too much effort. However, it seems like using this project is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup breaks the Angular bootstrap system. So you have to add the [manual boostrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) procedure  in your hello.js file.

```
require(["app"], function(app) {
    app.controller("Hello", ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log('function entered');
            $scope.sayHello = function() {
                console.log('Hello');
                return "Hello";
            }

            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            });

        }]
    );
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it did not change anything. I noticed that it has a (document).ready call in it. Does that depend on jQuery, or is it a separate element in Angular?

Comment: angular contains its own subset of jquery. If you don't use jquery it works with this subset, if you do you get the full package from jquery.

Comment: The link from Shay Friedman suggests that it's really a timing problem. Have a look into that code.